# Remove zero value head and tail rows from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a collection of DataFrames with zero-value head and tail rows. I would like to drop these zero-value rows and keep the range between them.

For example, given this DataFrame:

```
   x
0  0
1  0
2  1 
3  0
4  3
5  1
6  0
7  0
```

I would like a function that returns this:

```
   x
2  1 
3  0
4  3
5  1
```

Note that the zero value at row 3 has not been lost. I'm not wanting to remove all zeroes, only the head and tail. How can this be done with Pandas?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df = df[df['x'].cumsum().mul(df['x'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()).ne(0)]
print (df)
   x
2  1
3  0
4  3
5  1
```

**Explanation**:

Get [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of column:

```
print (df['x'].cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    4
5    5
6    5
7    5
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Invert column and again `cumsum`:

```
print (df['x'].iloc[::-1].cumsum())
7    0
6    0
5    1
4    4
3    4
2    5
1    5
0    5
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
print (df['x'].cumsum().mul(df['x'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()))
0     0
1     0
2     5
3     4
4    16
5     5
6     0
7     0
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

And check for not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) `(!=)` of `0`:

```
print (df['x'].cumsum().mul(df['x'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()).ne(0))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Thank you, @Wen for another solution:

```
df[(df.x.eq(0).cumprod().eq(0))&(df.x[::-1].eq(0).cumprod().eq(0))]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: Sure, give me some time.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can add`df[(df.x.eq(0).cumprod().eq(0))&(df.x[::-1].eq(0).cumprod().eq(0))]
`

Answer (score 3):

It can also be useful. `nonzero` will give indices of the non zero elements in the series. Access first and last index of the tuple will generate the expected output

```
import pandas as pd
df2=pd.DataFrame({'cols':[0,0,1,0,3,1,0,0]})
non_zero_index = df2.cols.nonzero()[0]
start, end = non_zero_index[0],non_zero_index[-1]
df2.loc[start:end]
    cols
2   1
3   0
4   3
5   1
```

Comment: Using loc not iloc

Comment: I really like this solution the best. +1

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays with few zeros, manual iteration will be more efficient than Boolean indexing. For example, via a generator expression with `next` and `enumerate`:

```
start = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(df['x']) if val != 0)
end = -next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(df['x'].iloc[::-1]) if val != 0)

res = df['x'].iloc[start:end]

2    1
3    0
4    3
5    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll put my horse in this race too.

Cumsum forward, cumsum backwards, take the minimum value if equal to zero discard.

```
df[np.minimum(df['x'].cumsum(), df['x'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]).ne(0)]
```

Output:

```
   x
2  1
3  0
4  3
5  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspire by [mad_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297785/7964527)

```
df.loc[df.x.mask(df.x==0).first_valid_index():df.x.mask(df.x==0).last_valid_index()]
Out[39]: 
   x
2  1
3  0
4  3
5  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'x':[0,0,1,2,1,0,0,4,4,0,0]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Remove tail zeros:

```
i=len(df)-1
x=df['x'][i]

while x==0:
    i-=1
    x=df['x'][i]
df=df[0:i+1]
```

Remove head zeros:

```
while x==0:
    del df['x'][i]
    i-=1
    x=df['x'][i]
df=df[i:]
```